# How to Import IModuleManager Inside a Module

Tags: prism

The Question About PrismApplication. I Use Prism4 with MEF on a WPF Application,

The Error Occurred When Import IModuleManager Inside a Module

**error:The exception message was: GetExportedValue cannot be called before prerequisite import 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager..ctor(Parameter="moduleInitializer", ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleInitializer")' has been set.**

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(IPlugIn))]
public class NavModule : IPlugIn
{
    [Import]
    private IRegionManager RegionManger;

    [Import]
    private IModuleManager ModuleManager;

    public string Caption
    {
       .....
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may find a proper answer to your same question on the following **CodePlex** thread:

- [Problem with importing IModuleManager in a Module](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/354228)

It seems that there is a timing issue when composing the **IModuleInitializer**, which causes to throw the exception you described. However, this only happens with **Modules** registered in Code through the **AggregateCatalog**.

You can see the issue that has already been reported in the following link, with a workaround posted by the community:

- [Importing IModuleManager Inside a Module with Mef](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/9374)

I hope this helped you, 
Regards.